# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable while doing s-expression in Python

Tags: python, recursion, s-expression

I am trying to write a basic s-expression calculator in Python using s-expression which can contains add or multiply or both or none or just an integar number.

I tried the following snippet:

```
def calc(expr):
    print(expression[0])
    if isinstance(expr, int):
        return expr
    elif expr[0] == '+':
        return calc(expr[1]) + calc(expr[2])
    elif expr[0] == '*':
        return calc(expr[1]) * calc(expr[2])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown operator: %s" % expr[0])

# Example usage
# expression = ('+', ('*', 3, 4), 5)
expression = (7)
result = calc(expression)
print(result)
```

When I tried to pass the expression `('+', ('*', 3, 4), 5)` , it gives the correct answer but when I just try to use number 7 or 7 inside tuple (7), it gives the above error. How to solve this?

Comment: remove `print(expression[0])`

Comment: Or place it after the branch that exclude the int type.

Comment: You get an error from `7` because it isn't an s-expression - you are using tuples to represent your s-expressions, and `7` is an integer, not a tuple. You also get an error from `(7)` because that is **still** not a tuple - it **means the same thing** as `7` (they're just ordinary parentheses like in math). To make that tuple, a trailing comma is needed: `(7,)`. I linked this as a duplicate of the canonical about making such tuples, because that is the underlying problem here.

Comment: Ah, I see. You intend to handle `int`s specially (since there's recursion anyway). There are multiple issues with the debugging `print`: first, it's accessing the global `expression` instead of the passed-in `expr`, and second it's trying to access an element of the tuple before verifying that there is actually a tuple. I think both of these qualify as typos.

Answer (score 0):

## Code is fine, debug is not

You `print` used to debug is not correctly placed, or assume expression to be a Sequence, not an int.

1. **[Good practice]** Don't print a global variable but local: `print(expr)`.
   This is less confusing and will help you for debugging this code.
2. **[Branch simplification]** Replace every `elif` with `if`. Since you return in every branch, you don't need `elif`. Remove the `else` too. This will allows you to place code after the first if that will be run for all remaining branches without having to place it in every `elif`.

```py
def calc(expr: int | tuple):
    print(expr)
    if isinstance(expr, int):
        return expr
    if expr[0] == '+':
        return calc(expr[1]) + calc(expr[2])
    if expr[0] == '*':
        return calc(expr[1]) * calc(expr[2])
    raise ValueError("Unknown operator: %s" % expr[0])
```

3. **[Fix]** Move the `print` below the first `if`.

```py
def calc(expr: int | tuple):
    if isinstance(expr, int):
        return expr
    print(expr)
    if expr[0] == '+':
        return calc(expr[1]) + calc(expr[2])
    if expr[0] == '*':
        return calc(expr[1]) * calc(expr[2])
    raise ValueError("Unknown operator: %s" % expr[0])
```

This code works, both for `(7)` and `('+', ('*', 3, 4), 5)`.